# Adding a hyphen to the html attribute name using MVC3 WebGrid helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I'm having a problem trying to add a custom HTML5 data attribute to the table that is rendered using the WebGrid helper.  I want the table tag look as follows:

```
<table data-test="testdata"><!-- Table Content --></table>
```

Here is a sample view using the Razor view engine:

```
@{
    var myUser = new
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Test User"
    };

    var users = new[] { myUser };

    var grid = new WebGrid(users);
}
@grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { data-test = "testdata"})
```

The last line will produce a "Invalid anonymous type member declarator." error, because of the hyphen in data-test.

With some of the other input HtmlHelpers, you can use an underscore in place of the hyphen and it will be automatically changed to a hyphen when rendered.  This does not happen with the WebGrid.

If I pass in a dictionary for htmlAttributes:

```
@grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new Dictionary<string, object> {{ "data-test", "testdata"}})
```

the table gets rendered as such:

```
<table Comparer="System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[System.String]" Count="1" Keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]" Values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]"><!-- Table Content --></table>
```

What am I doing wrong and what should I do render the attribute as desired?

Comment: what happens when you put `@` infront of your attribute name? if you want to add an attribute of class you need to type `@class` because `class` is special, would this also apply to your special attribute?

Comment: Putting @ in front has the same behavior as not having it there.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I am afraid that this is not possible. Unfortunately the WebGrid it doesn't support the same syntax as standard HTML helper such as `TextBoxFor` where you could:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProp, new { data_test = "testdata" })
```

and the underscore would be automatically converted to dash.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work with Html.BeginForm()  so we had to do it this way     @using (Html.BeginForm("view", "controller", FormMethod.Post,new Dictionary<string, object>{{ "data-test", "testdata" }} ))